# Widely accepted methods for coming up with the co-variance matrix of assets?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, covariance, covariance-matrix

### Question

What are the widely accepted ways for coming up with co-variance matrix of assets
after the Markowitz's modern portfolio theory?

### Question explained in more detail

1. After Modern portfolio theory was introduced, to my best knowledge, there are bunch of new theories of co-variance methods came out.
2. [Exponential co-variance matrix](https://reasonabledeviations.science/2018/08/15/exponential-covariance/) and [Ledoit-Wolf](https://jpm.iijournals.com/content/30/4/110) are two examples of those new methods.
3. Can somebody tell me the more recent advancement of the co-variance matrix to create a portfolio? If the paper has a github code written in Python, it would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multivariate volatility models for replacing the sample covariance matrix with in the mean-variance portfolio selection model:

1. **RiskMetrics 1996 EWMA (Exponentially weighted moving average) covariance matrix**
2. **RiskMetrics 2006 EWMA covariance matrix**
3. **Multivariate DCC-GARCH covariance matrix**

   - Jon Danielsson "Financial risk forecasting" has EWMA and GARCH for [R and Matlab](https://www.financialriskforecasting.com/code/3.html) and looks like Python now too.
   - Kevin Sheppard's [MFE toolbox for Matlab](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/MFE_Toolbox) and [Arch package for Python](https://pypi.org/project/arch/) have EWMA and GARCH. RiskMetrics 2006 EWMA for Python is [here](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/volatility.html#riskmetrics-2006).
4. **Ledoit and Wolf (2003) covariance matrix based on the single factor index model:**

   - Ledoit, O. and Wolf, M. (2003). Improved estimation of the covariance matrix of stock returns with an application to portfolio selection. Journal of Empirical Finance, 10:603-621.
   - [Matlab code](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-0000-0000648dfc98/covMarket.m.zip)
5. **Ledoit and Wolf (2004) covariance matrix based on the identity matrix:**

   - Ledoit, O. and Wolf, M. (2004). A well-conditioned estimator for large-dimensional covariance matrices. Journal of Multivariate Analysis, 88:365-411.
   - [Matlab code](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-0000-00007f64e5b9/cov1para.m.zip)
   - [Python code](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.LedoitWolf.html) (Sci-kit learn package)

See the second author's publication page if links change at https://www.econ.uzh.ch/en/people/faculty/wolf/publications.html

Answer (score 2):

Ledoit and Wolf have a new paper ( November 2018 ) called *"Analytical Nonlinear Shrinkage of Large-Dimensional Covariance Matrices"* which has MATLAB code for the procedure at the end of the paper. The paper can be downloaded at [SSRN](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3047302).